# how can I achieve similar functionality as <mvc:resources> in spring 3.0.0?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

As I found   this tag   was introduced in spring 3.0.4 and I am using spring 3.0.0. So how can I achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Why not simply upgrade the latests 3.0 bug fix?

Comment: This would have a bigger impact on the project and project is stable right now. so I can't upgrade  the version

Comment: Why? It is a drop in replacement, so changing a version number in your pom.xml (assuming you use maven) is a bigger issue then trying to correctly mimic the behavior of a spring tag.